# Is this way of creating "truly" random string makes sense?

Tags: php, algorithm, security, random, hash

Good time of the day,
Lately, I've been playing around with Laravel Echo, and came to the conclusion that for any operations with sensitive information, i need a token, which will be secure enough to be used as a broadcast channel.

So my idea of generating the "truly" random, yet based on some data token is the following:

1. Create random string of 127 characters
2. Hash username with SHA-512
3. Hash email with SHA-512
4. Hash first name with SHA-512
5. Hash last name with SHA-512
6. Hash current timestamp with SHA-512
7. Combine hashed strings and hash them with SHA-512 again
8. Combine random string (127 characters) and hashed 5 strings (128 characters)

So what I've ended up with is 255 characters string. This token is regenerated on every login, so it is pretty much "strong"?

So, is it possible to achieve the same goal with less "hassle", or this is pretty much the best approach to achieve "most security" for any sensitive data?

```
/**
 * Generate truly random string for broadcast_token
 * @param App\Models\User $user
 * @return string
 */
function broadcast_id(\App\Models\User $user) : string {
    $algorithm = 'sha512';
    $randomString = \Illuminate\Support\Str::random(127);
    $usernameHash = hash($algorithm, $user->username);
    $emailHash = hash($algorithm, $user->email);
    $firstNameHash = hash($algorithm, $user->first_name);
    $lastNameHash = hash($algorithm, $user->last_name);
    $timeHash = hash($algorithm, time());
    $hashedData = hash($algorithm, sprintf('%s:%s:%s:%s:%s', $usernameHash, $emailHash, $firstNameHash, $lastNameHash, $timeHash));
    return sprintf('%s%s', $randomString, $hashedData);
}
```

Comment: Or just use [`random_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) and store the token with the user's metadata.

Comment: @Sammitch but how truly random this token will be while used in application with 100k+ active users?

Comment: The number of users does not affect the randomness of the token.

Comment: Are you looking for something random, or something secure? If you just want to generate a token, perhaps you could hash the username with a salt.

Comment: @Mike maybe i'm just a bit late to the party, but (i might be completely wrong) i've read that some PHP generator methods may provide the same hash due to "different implementations" on different OSes. But since `random_bytes()` suggested to be the best approach, i will probably stick with it then.

Comment: @RToyo i know that i'm asking for too much, but i want these both. It is pretty unacceptable to get two users with same token at the same time since it will compromise the account.

Comment: If you want unique tokens, store the token in a database (associate it with the user), and check when creating a new token if one already exists with that value (which is extremely unlikely). If it exists, create a new token and check again. Repeat until success. `random` != `unique`

Comment: If you want "secure" then you need to go full "random", which has the extra benefit of just being a call to `random_bytes()` rather than wasting all those CPU cycles on hashing. 255 random bytes are far more difficult to guess/crack than 128 deterministic bytes and 127 random bytes.

Comment: There are also [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s if you want uniqueness. Depending on your database engine, it might be able to generate them for you.

Comment: If you generate a string using `random_bytes` that is always of the same length and put the user's id behind it, the string should always be unique.

Comment: Are you looking for "random," or "unique?" Perhaps "unique and random," although that's a rather fuzzy concept.

Answer (score 0):

> for any operations with sensitive information, i need a token, which will be secure enough to be used as a broadcast channel.

Okay.

> 1. Create random string of 127 characters
>
> [snip]
>
> So what I've ended up with is 255 characters string. This token is regenerated on every login, so it is pretty much "strong"?

Your goal is a random string, so you start with a random string?

This seems like a hassle.

> So, is it possible to achieve the same goal with less "hassle", or this is pretty much the best approach to achieve "most security" for any sensitive data?

Easy:

```
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
```

Hashing a bunch of stuff together just adds a minor computational overhead to your script, it doesn't really make anything secure.

With a 32-byte random string, you'll have your first collision (with 50%) probability after about 2^128 tokens are generated. You will never reach this number in your lifetime.